# My onclick function isn't working because the function won't change the boolean value

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm trying to make a webpage that when you click on both buttons it'll change the background color, but for some reason that event won't happen unless i change them from the original variable. I think it's because my functions aren't getting and changing my variable's value for some reason but there may be another reason that i can't see. Is there a correct way to change variable values inside functions that i'm not using?

```js
let uno = false;
let dos = false;

function change1() {
  uno = true;
  return uno;
}

function change2() {
  dos = true;
  return dos;
}

if (uno && dos) {
  document.body.classList.add("change");
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #8AB0AB;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.change {
  background-color: #F4D35E;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <button id="1" onclick="change1()">
#1
</button>
  <button id='2' onclick="change2()">
#2
</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The `if` statement only runs when the page first loads. It doesn't check again after each click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to evaluate the state after the button is clicked. Something like:

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
var isOn = true;

if(buttons){
  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
      this.classList.toggle("highlight");
      evaluateButtons();
    });
  }
}

function evaluateButtons(){
    isOn = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        if(!buttons[i].classList.contains("highlight")){
            isOn = false;
        }
    }
    if (isOn){
      document.body.classList.add("modified");
    } else {
      document.body.classList.remove("modified");
    }    
}
```

```css
.highlight{
  background-color: green;
}
.modified{
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button>
    #1
  </button>
  <button>
    #2
  </button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're only checking the boolean variables once, when the page first loads, not after the clicks change the values of the variables.

You need to run the `if (uno && dos)` code after every click on one of the buttons, to update the body class.

There's no need for the `return` statements in the functions, since the return value of `onXXX()` functions isn't used.

```js
let uno = false;
let dos = false;

function change1() {
  uno = true;
  change_body();
}

function change2() {
  dos = true;
  change_body();
}

function change_body() {
  if (uno && dos) {
    document.body.classList.add("change");
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #8AB0AB;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.change {
  background-color: #F4D35E;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <button id="1" onclick="change1()">
#1
</button>
  <button id='2' onclick="change2()">
#2
</button>
</body>

</html>
```